# How to get each element in constant time?

Tags: performance, sorting, data-structures, element

We got **n** elements and **n** boxes to them store them. Each elemt has an id-number of 10 digits. How can we store these elements so that we have access to each element in constant time?

I thought storing them in an ascending sequence (id-number) or vice versa. But this would cause a running time of n in the worst-case. How would you store them?

Comment: You could use a Perfect hash function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a perfect hash-function.

Access to the elements in constant time. O(1) in the worst case

Here is the link to wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function